# Android - Button under Relative layout wont initiate OnClickListener when clicked

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, onclicklistener

Hello this is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tutorialBox"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closeBen"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/CloseBenny"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bennybox"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/chatbub" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i have made an on click listener for it

```
  final Button closeBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeBen);
    closeBt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeBt.setText("Im a button");
        }
    });
```

for some reason when i click this button nothing happens it doesnt look like it has been clicked.
when i took the button out of the realtive layout everything worked fine
any suggestions?

Comment: Your XML looks weird, where are the RelativeLayout attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this add onClick attribute to the button tag in xml.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/closeBen"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/CloseBenny"
    android:onClick = "close_clicked"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bennybox"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/chatbub" />
```

Then in Main Activity just make a new method like this.

```
public void close_clicked (View v){
   // Your code
}
```

No need to add on click listner.

Comment: Tried that before no use.

Comment: Remove final keyword while initializing button because then after you cannot change the text attribute of the button.

Comment: Android studio wont allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RelativeLayout` does not look good, is it your main container?
 Maybe try it this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/closeBen"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/CloseBenny"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bennybox"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/chatbub" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And a good practice is to declare your widgets globally then instantiate them in the`OnCreate`

```
public class Foo extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button closeBenny;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    closeBenny = (Button)findViewById(R.id.closeBen);
    closeBenny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            closeBenny.setText("Im a button");
        }
    });
  }
}
```